# Best way to mock Redis/MongoDB in HTTP Flask endpoint request unit tests

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, redis, pytest

I have a Flask API ('app') that is defined similar to this:

```
import redis 
import pymongo
...

redis_client=redis.connect("redis url")
mongo_client = mongo.connect("mongo url")

@app.route('/dostuff', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def do_stuff_with_dbs():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      redis_client.lpush(post_data)
      mongo_client.create_one(post_data)
      return 200
   if request.method == 'GET':
      list = redis_client.lrange(list, 0 ,-1)
      docs = mongo_client.find({})
      return list, docs
```

I want to define a test that can call the endpoint, but the API creates it's own db connections so i'm not sure how to mock them since they aren't passed in.

This is what i'm wanting to do:

```
from app import app

def test_get():
   response = app.test_client().get('/dostuff')
   assert response.status_code = 200
   assert response.data == {[list], {docs}}
   ...
```

I have found a lot of info on how to mock a redis client that you pass in but these endpoints dont take a redis client parameter so i'm not sure how to fake a connection on the app's side.

Any info or resources would be much appreciated.

I've tried mocking some instances of redis but keep getting errors when the app tries to connect to redis.

Comment: Why are you looking for mocking? I think that making `redis_client` and `mongo_client` point to a test database instance (one different that the production ones) would provide you the same functionality but better testing.

Comment: That would also work, I just wasn't able to find any examples of how to do that.

Comment: My answer includes a way to make it point to a test database. As I mentioned there, you shall be safe as far as you don't invoke test functions, or similar from the app.

Answer (score 0):

For Mocking you can use the [Mock Object Library from unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). For a simple use, you could do this:

```
from app import app, redis_client, mongo_client
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_get():
   redis_return_example = []
   mongo_return_example = {}
   redis_client.lrange = MagicMock(return_value=redis_return_example)
   mongo_client.find =  MagicMock(return_value=mongo_return_example)
   response = app.test_client().get('/dostuff')
   assert response.status_code = 200
   assert response.data == {[list], {docs}}
   ...
```

Just to clarify, this would Mock only the functions `lrange` and `find` from `redis_client` and `mongo_client` respectively. If you want to mock more functions or the whole objects take a look to the library documentation.

As a personal note, instead of mocking, I would suggest you to make them point to a database created for testing. This would allow you for better testing as you could test the whole data flow. For doing that, you could simply do something like:

```
from app import app, redis_client, mongo_client

def test_get():
   redis_client = redis.connect("redis test url")     # Redefine the Redis database object before the test
   mongo_client = mongo.connect("mongo test url")   # Redefine the Mongo database object before the test
   response = app.test_client().get('/dostuff')
   assert response.status_code = 200
   assert response.data == {[list], {docs}}
   ...
```

Also, if you are gonna do testing, I recommend you to take a look to [python unittest library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) which is very useful.

Comment: In the example you give for using the test databases, how does that overwrite the redis and mongo clients defined in the api's code?  Would the clients redefined in the tests not have to be passed in to the app somehow?

Comment: Well, the `redis_client` and the `mongo_client` are objects that define the connection. When you import them on your test, you are importing the reference to those object. The overwrite does modify the object but not the reference. As the reference is unchanged, when the function api is changed, it uses the new object created after calling the test function and not the previous one created on file load.

Comment: About the second question,  the overwrite will not be propagated into the app unless you execute the test function `test_get()` on the app.